# What should I do in my webpage so that only a user from a web browser can request a page and post some data and not from user using Fiddler?

Tags: php, post, fiddler, developer-tools

I recently created two pages, front-end.php and back-end.php.
front-end.php post some data to back-end.php on mouse click (I am currently using ajax for this).

Now if I use Fiddler, then also I am able to post data to back-end.php. I do not want this to happen. What should I do?

I searched on Internet for answer and came to a word 'Setting User_agent', but solution is not given clearly.

Regarding what I want, Actually I do not want some bot or some other type of automatic program to get some data from some source and post it to my back-end.php. I want to assure that the user comes to my webpage and then post some data.

Answer (score 1):

User Agent is a header that your browser sends to the web server with each request identifying itself.  [Here you can see](http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/) what it is like.

Fiddler sends "*" or "Fiddler" as user agent, so you can ignore requests having those values. However, this is far from optimal solution to your problem because one can simply spoof the user-agent header by sending whatever she likes.

An other non-secure condition would be to check [the referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). So, you can ignore all requests except those coming from "front-end.php". Keep in mind that this, too, can be spoofed by the user.

You should keep also in mind that since a user can send data to the web-server using her browser, there is nothing that can stop her from sending data or making requests using any other way.

In general, web developers should respect the user's freedom and not force such tactics, so please be more specific and tell us what exactly is the *real* problem you want to solve and a more elegant/secure solution may exist.

EDIT: If you do not want crawlers to index some/all of your pages you should add them in your [robots.txt file.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

Regarding all other automations/programs I'm afraid there is no perfect way to be sure if the request was made from a human being or a robot. I would do two things: a) Make sure to add validation rules to my backend and b) as a last resort implement [a CAPTCHA test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA).

I would use CAPTCHA only if absolute necessary because it irritates most users and makes their lives difficult.

Comment: Okay. I got it. Regarding what I want, Actually I do not want some bot or some other type of automatic program to get some data from some source and post it to my back-end.php. I want to assure that the user comes to my webpage and then post some data.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a hash of some internal secret and the value you want to send. As you are the only one who knows how to make the hash, a fiddler cannot know how to create the secret.

For instance, you make a hash of "asdflj8######GJlk" concatenated by whatever your value in your form is. Now the hacker cannot change the form. The problem is, you *can* post the same value (with the same hash) from another place. To stop this from happening you should make sure all hashes can be used only once. The only thing a hacker can do now is to post your request from fiddler *instead* of from your site, but not at the same time. As a final step you can add something as a time-limitation

So what you need is a hash with:

- a secret
- a method to make the hash single-use
- a methode to make the hash time-limited

add this as a field. Specific implementation is left as an exercise ;)

I would not use user_agent, these can be easily faked.

(these methods are the same that payment-providers use to ensure the data (e.g. the amount to be payed!) is not tampered with)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer is that **anything your browser can do, Fiddler can do**. It can send any header it wants using any value it wants.

If your goal is to be able to pass some values from one page to another, without ANYONE changing them (either the browser or Fiddler) you use a Message Authentication Code (a signed hash of the data).

ASP.NET builds this feature in for their "ViewState" data; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enableviewstatemac(v=vs.110).aspx

However, that precludes the client (e.g. your JavaScript) from changing the values at all; if JavaScript can change the values, it means that it has the key, and if it has the key, so does Fiddler.